# PopAsync causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm pretty new to `Xamarin.Forms`. I have a pretty simple function on main page appearing

```
async public Task BaseAppearing()
    {
        if (UserID == null)
        {
            var page = new LoginPage();
            await App.Navigate(page);
        }
        else
        {
            stopWatch.Restart();
        }
    }
```

Now the login page shows all right, problem is that in the login page when I click on Login and I try to pop the navigation stack, I get the following error

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

and the app crashes.

Exception happens only in Android (emulator and real). in UWP it works just fine

The popping code is also very simple

```
public static Task PopNavigation()
    {
        var nav = Current.MainPage.Navigation;
        Task ret;
        try
        {
            ret = nav.PopAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log();
            ret = Navigate(Current.MainPage);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Not only does it throw the error, but it never reaches the exception handler.

Also, I've read that sometimes the navigation stack becomes corrupted/empty. But no, `NavigationStack` has 2 items. MainPage and LoginPage, which I believe is correct

All navigation is happening on the same stack, since I only have 1 navigation function in the app and that's all I ever call for navigation

Please advise what can be done

**UPDATE**
I tried to change my code to use `NavigationPage` as follows, but did not help (also i got like 2 title bars on top)

```
public async static Task Navigate(Page Page)
    {
        //await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( Page);
        await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( new NavigationPage( Page));
    }
```

If this might help someone, here's my stack trace

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32
>   index) [0x00009] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs:180
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.GetFragment
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean removed, System.Boolean
>   popToRoot) [0x00003] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:865
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.SwitchContentAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated, System.Boolean
>   removed, System.Boolean popToRoot) [0x0001a] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:768
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPopViewAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00017] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:592
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.PopViewAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:154
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPopped
>   (System.Object sender,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:573
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__69.MoveNext
>   () [0x0004c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:297 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__68.MoveNext ()
>   [0x0004c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:280 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__45.MoveNext
>   () [0x000cb] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:168 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at Qleeg.LoginPage+d__2.MoveNext ()
>   [0x003f8] in D:\Projects\Qleeg\Qleeg\Qleeg\Views\LoginPage.xaml.cs:70 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.30(intptr,intptr)   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   System.Object.30(intptr,intptr)

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the app's constructor

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => OnError(sender, args.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) => OnError(sender, args.Exception);
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
   ......
}
```

And here is my navigation code

From MainPage to LoginPage

```
async public static Task BaseAppearing(this ContentPage Input)
{
    if (App.Current.UserID == null)
    {
        var page = new LoginPage();
        await Input.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    }
    else
    {
        App.Current.stopWatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

And Back

```
lblMessage.Text = "Welcome!";
lblMessage.TextColor = Color.Green;
Functions.WriteLog("Login", "pre nav pop");
//await App.PopNavigation();// App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
await Navigation.PopAsync();//THIS IS LINE 70
```

**UPDATE 3**

I switched my MainPage code to this:

```
    async private void MainPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.Current.UserID == null) {await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new LoginPage ())); }
    }
```

Now, The error disappeared (though I'm baffled as to the reason), but `Navigaion.PopAsync()` simply does nothing. No error, but no navigating either.

Also, LoginPage now appears with 2 title lines/headers on the top.

Comment: Are you using a NavigationPage?

Comment: hi. if i understood you correctly, then I tried. But no, it didn't help. Please see updae in post. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using some third-part plugin for navigation? See how navigation push in xamarin.forms here: [navigation/hierarchical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for chipping in. No. I'm not using any third party plugin. And yes, I've read that article, And it seems that my code is correct. Moreover, in `UWP` it works flawlessly. (I'm supposed to only use the navigation of one page throughout the system, and not of each seperate page. Correct?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

`Task.Delay(300)`

before navigating page.

i know it's an hack
but if you want to navigate to other page while on appearing then we have to do this.
cause whole page is not initialized yet.
so we have to wait for couple of seconds to initialize page properly in navigation stack

Answer (score 2):

If you Push a page in `OnAppearing` on Android, it won't be initialised properly and subsequent calls to `PopAsync` or simply pressing the back button in the toolbar will cause this error. To bypass, you have to introduce a delay so that the main page can be initialised properly first.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{ 
    base.OnAppearing();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(500)).ContinueWith(async (t) =>
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage(), false);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a NavigationPage to your root page:

```
public App ()
{
  MainPage = new NavigationPage (new Page1Xaml ());
}
```

To push a page simplily:

```
async void OnNextPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2Xaml ());
}
```

To pop a page :

```
async void OnPreviousPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PopAsync ();
}
```

To pop to root page:

```
async void OnRootPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
}
```

Use the codes I listed above to push and pop pages in xamarin.forms.  I can't understand what is `await App.Navigate(page);` in your project.

> I tried to change my code to use NavigationPage as follows, but did
>   not help (also i got like 2 title bars on top)

You only need one instance of NavigationPage in your project. Don't push to a new NavigationPage like this:

```
await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( new NavigationPage( Page));
```

Just push to the page you want:

```
 await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(Page);
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your detailed explanations. But I'm afraid I'm doing eveything per the book. I cannot seem to see any differences between my code and yours. I've repasted my snippets towards the end of my post under 'Update 2'. can you maybe shed some light on mys mistake? Thanks again!

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski You codes looks good. And can you check what is the codes in LoginPage.xaml.cs:70, the error seems happen there. And if you can share more code of the pages, we can find out the mistake easier.

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski Can you try use Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( new NavigationPage( Page)); instead of using Input.Navigation.PushAsync(page);. Remove the Input.

Comment: Hi. Your code stops the error throwing, but navigation doesn't work now either. Also I have now 2 titles in the second page. Please see update 3 in original post for complete results. thanks again so much for your caring.

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski 1.Push to the page directly instead of push to a NavigationPage: `await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage ());`. 2. Try `Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync ();`.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my late response, I was on other issues.  I tried both things you wrote, but no go. Same error with the IndexOutOfRange